# Domain Whois Information Algorithm

Tags: scripting, dns, names, verisign

Is it possible to run an algorithm of all the verisign (and maybe individual registrars whois) domain data to call out qualified information?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Zone File Access program that is operated by all the registries, as a condition of operating the TLD by ICANN, that will allow you to get a list of all the domain names that are registered.  There are strict rules on what you can do with such data but it might be a route forward.

I believe that there are existing companies that have done this and you can query them instead.  It all depends on how much data you require as to which method is cheaper.

Hope that this helps

Jonathan

Comment: Thank Jonathan.  Do you know any companies that are currently doing something similar?  I did connect with Savespell and Domain Graveyard to ask them.  They are basically looking at the same info I'd like to review. In there case they are looking for different qualifying data than I'm after.  Ideally, I want to trim down my query to even ten matches - that would be fantastic.

Comment: Hi - As an example I would like to search for any domains that match a preset criteria -  as an example, I may want to look up a specific geographic location of the current owner.  I may want only domains that have had at least two previous owners.  I may want traditional criteria such as common English words (1 or 2), etc.

Comment: I hit RETURN a little too fast -- I'm looking to come up with a short list for our domain service startup.